# Is there any way to use an pre-animated animation on a character?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I'm pretty new to Blender, I've got the basics so I wanted to move on to something a little bit harder. I have a pre-rigged character and the idle animation I got is from the site ActorCore (https://actorcore.reallusion.com/motion?orderBy=Relevance&keyword=idle&asset=idle_251087) I was wondering if there was any way to add the premade animation on to my character? Every time I try the bones and mesh get crumbled up. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: the action will move the bones of your armature as long as they share the same name, if it's the case, you can still meet some problems if the orientation of your bones are not correct, in that case switch your armature to Edit mode and try to roll some bones (Ctrl R 90 for example)

Comment: Is there any way I could delete/ un-parent the bones in my character mesh and just replace them with the imported bones of the animation?

Comment: sure you can try this